# How `erl -make` does its work?

Tags: erlang

I found files won't be compiled in following situation with `erl -make`.

1. Compile file `a.erl`
2. Copy an old version of `a.erl` from other directory
3. Compile file `a.erl`
4. `a.erl` not compiled

Then I tested it on OS X, `a.erl` was compiled successfully.

In above two situations, the only difference is that the 'last modified time' in OS X was changed when I copy the file with `cp` command, while not changed in Windows without command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've already figured it out: recompilation is triggered when the source file is newer than the compiled file.  Your Windows shell is preserving the modification time, so we don't recompile.  The Mac OS terminal shell (bash) updates the modification time, so the old file looks new.

Here's the relevant section of the make(3) manual page:

> ```
>           Traversing the set of modules, it then recompiles  every  module
>           for which at least one of the following conditions apply:
>
>            * there is no object file, or
>
>            * the  source  file  has  been modified since it was last com-
>               piled, or,
>
>            * an include file has been modified since the source file  was
>               last compiled.
>
>          As a side effect, the function prints the name of each module it
>           tries to compile. If compilation fails for a  module,  the  make
>           procedure stops and error is returned.
> ```

Under Windows, your best bet is to delete the compiled module when you want to force a recompile.  You might also have a better time using some source control (SVN, Git, etc).  I believe that they would update the modification time of a reverted file, even under Windows.